# Cannot access Firebase remote config console, getting error: There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

This happened after someone (we dont know yet) deleted our Firebase project, we just Restore the project and everything works fine but the Remote config, we are getting all the time the error: "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again." and cannot access the console, any ideas?

Comment: If you're having a problem with the console, contact [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly for assistance.

Comment: Just wait several hours. Then the restore will be completed.